# Trying to match string A if string B is found anywhere before it

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

What I'm trying to do is, if a string consists of some substring that starts with "!" encapsulated in "[" and "]", to separate those brackets from the rest of the string via a space, e.g. "[!foo]" --> "[ !foo ]", "[!bar]" --> "[ !bar ]", etc. Since that substring can be variable length, I figured this had to be done with regex. My thought was to do this in two steps - first separate the first bracket, then separate the second bracket.

The first one isn't hard; the regex is just `\[!` and so I can just do `str = str.replace(/\[!/g, "[ !");` in Javascript. It's the second part I can't get to work.

Because now, I need to match "]" if the string literal "[ !" is found *anywhere* before it. So a simple positive lookbehind doesn't match because it only looks *directly* behind: `(?<=\Q[ !\E)\]` doesn't match.

And I still don't understand why, but I'm not allowed to make the positive lookbehind non-fixed length; `(?<=\Q[ !\E.*)\]` throws the error `Syntax Error: Invalid regular expression: missing /` in the console, and [this regex debugger](https://regex101.com/) yields a pattern error explaining "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width".

Putting a non-capturing group of non-fixed width between the lookbehind and the capturing group doesn't work; `(?<=\Q[ !\E)(?:.*)\]` doesn't match.

One thing that won't work is just trying to match "[ !" at the start of the string, because this whole "[!foo]" string is actually *itself* a substring of an even bigger string and isn't at the beginning.

What am I missing?

Comment: In JS, those ECMAScript2018 compliant environments allow using infinite width lookbehind - why are you testing at regex101 using PCRE option if you are using the regex in JS? `/(?<!A.*?)B/gs` is the generic pattern to find any `B` not preceded with `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2 positive lookarounds, you can assert what is on the left is an opening square bracket `(?<=\[)`

Then match any char except `]` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `![^[\]]+` preceded by an exclamation mark and assert what is on the right is a closing square bracket using `(?=])`

Note that in Javascript the lookbehind is not yet widely supported.

```
(?<=\[)![^[\]]+(?=])
```

In the [replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) use the matched substring `$&`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpqwnz/1)

```js
[
  "[!foo]",
  "[!bar]"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(/(?<=\[)![^[\]]+(?=])/g, " $& "))
)
```

---

Or you could also use 3 capturing groups instead:

```
(\[)(![^\]]+)(\])
```

In the replacement use

```
$1 $2 $3
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UMkNds/1)

```js
[
  "[!foo]",
  "[!bar]"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(/(\[)(![^\]]+)(\])/g, "$1 $2 $3"))
)
```

Comment: I made a slight edit to the regex in removing ! from the lookbehind so that it yields [ !foo ] and not [! foo ]. Otherwise that works great, thanks!

Comment: @Arcaeca Ah I see what you mean :) I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `\[!([^]]+)\]` with this substitution string `[! \1 ]`.

**Explanation**:

The regex:

- `\[!`: match begins with [!
- `([^]]+)`: capture in group 1 all the characters that are not ]
- `\]`: match ]

The substitution: substitute the full match with `[!`{contents of group 1}`]`.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4N5jNJ/2)

I hope it helps.